# Запрос Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Есть вот такая структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно выбрать для набора id-вагонов их type.id, type.name, type.price
Только type.price для всех вагонов одного типа суммировать.

Мой вариант не работает:

```
Carriage::with('type')
                ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3])
                ->select('types.id', 'types.name', 'types.price')
                ->groupBy('types.id')
                ->get();
```

Модель Carriage:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Carriage
 * @package App\Models
 */
class Carriage extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
    }
}
```

Модель Type:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Type
 * @package App\Models
 */
class Type extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function carriages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Carriage::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Модели приведите для обеихих таблиц

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Type::select('id', 'name')
    ->selectRaw('sum(price) as sum_price')
    ->whereHas('carriages', function($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);
    })
    ->groupBy('id, name')
    ->get();
```